# Change a String color [duplicated]!

Tags: android

```
String str = "Hello";
```

Is there any way to change the string color?
This question is probably duplicated, but all the answers are talking about changing a TextView color.
this string will be in a "text area".something like when the 
user types the word hello, then the output will be a hello word with (some color).

Comment: Be more specific about the question, where do you use that string?

Comment: All the answers talk about changing the `TextView` color because a `String` has no color.  Only the UI component that displays it has the property of color.

Comment: Strings as an object themselves do not have colors 'coded' into them.

Answer (score 1):

> this string will be in a "text area".something like when the user types the word hello, then the output will be a hello word with (some color).

I assume you mean that the user will be typing into an `EditText`. You can change the text color of an `EditText` with the following code.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
// choose a hex code for color
et.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
```

You can find examples of hex codes and their corresponding colors using a tool [such as this one](http://www.colorpicker.com/).

Comment: I meant in the example is that the word which between the double quotes "...". But I realized that the Strings are an object themselves do not have colors 'coded' into them as Ascorbin's comment.